# WInPython and PythonOCC

Tags: python, installation

Trying to Install PythonOCC into WinPython 2.7.6.4 without registering the WinPy version to the machine. As I am using a portable version of WinPython

Really struggling to get that to work. I have tried the package manager and it rejects the install.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So I found the solution from Google Code its an issue with the fiel name reader

[https://code.google.com/p/winpython/issues/detail?id=25](http://https://code.google.com/p/winpython/issues/detail?id=25)

Project Member #1 pierre.raybaut

That is only a limitation of the installer name (regular expression).  It should be already fixed in development version ("winpython" Python package). In the mean time, you may simply rename the installer so that there is no digit after 1.0b (or no "b3" at all).

I'll check if this is really fixed before closing this issue.